# Retriving child nodes from JSON response in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

```json
{
  "completionTime": 1477067415024,
  "context": {
    "environmentId": 78
  },
  "id": 51,
  "jobId": 473,
  "jobName": "Ravindra",
  "reportIds": [
    959
  ],
  "startTime": 1477067357196,
  "status": "PASSED",
  "username": "svc.soaess"
}
```

from this json structure I have to get the value 959.
`$response.ChildNodes.reportIds` displays blank.  Tried with array etc. no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably `$response` is a string, so you need to convert it to an object first, before you can access the object's properties.

```
($response | ConvertFrom-Json).reportIds
```